# Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on a non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I get this error msg Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on a non-object when I am trying to call a function from my model.
Here is the function:

```
public static function checkClaimById($claim_id) {
    $result = Claim::with('orders')
        ->find($claim_id)
        ->where('orders.user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->whereNull('deleted_at')
        ->count();
    if($result >= 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have the Model "claim" with has a field order_id and it belongs to an order.
And I have the model "order" and one Order has many claims.

Can someone help me?

thanks
Regards

Answer (score 2):

I have modified my function like this:

```
public static function checkClaimById($claim_id) {
    $result = Claim::with(array('orders' => function($query)
    {
        $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
    }))
    ->where('id', $claim_id)
    ->whereNull('deleted_at')
    ->count();

    if($result >= 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Found the solution here: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading